# How to use a condition in the listview item?

Tags: java, android, listview

Is it possible to index an item in a listview?

I have an Array with some names, 
I would like to identify the clicked name so I could make a condition, for example I clicked on "Andrew Murray" then from that item he will pull information from Andrew Murray in another Array with the person's name.

How could he do that?

My code:

```
// CRIANDO O ARRAY

        final String[] tituloFalas =

                {
 "A W Pink",
                        "A W Tozer",
                        "Abigail Van Buren",
                        "Abraham Kuyper",
                        "Adoniran Judson",
                        "Agostinho",
                        "Alexander Peden",
                        "Allan Redpath",
                        "Alvin Reid",
                        "Andrew Bonar",
                        "Andrew Murray",
                        "Andrew Young"
   };

  ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (

                        // Primeiro Parametro do Array Adpater é o Context

                        getApplicationContext(),

                        // Segundo Parametro do Array Adpater é o Layout

                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1,

                        // Terceiro Parametro do Array Adapter é indicar o nome do Array para exibição

                        tituloFalas

                );

        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

        // EVENTO DE CLIQUE

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Titulo.this,Autor.class);



                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: Pls put ur code here

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Put your logic in your `onListItemClick()` method (if using `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`) or in `onItemClick()` of your `OnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if(tituloFalas.get(position).equals("Andrew Murray"))
                     {
                     //Perform your task here
                     }
        }
    });
```